# Oracle SQL: Update with variable table name and fixed column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I am a beginner with SQL and have a problem: 
I have a DB with a big number of tables. Some of the tables have a column with the name "lab". 
In this colums are values I need to be changed.

So I managed to get the names of the tables via

```
SELECT CNAME,TNAME FROM SYSTEM.COL WHERE CNAME = 'LAB';
```

And I know my update command

```
update TNAME set LAB='VALUE' WHERE LAB='OLDVALUE'
```

But I can not manage to connect both statements via a variable TNAME or something. I tried to use execute immediate, but that did me no good.

Answer (score 0):

If its Oracle, something like this should do it:

```
BEGIN
    FOR cur_tabs_cols IN ( SELECT CNAME,TNAME FROM SYSTEM.COL WHERE CNAME = 'LAB'; )
    LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE ' || cur_tabs_cols.TNAME || ' SET LAB = ''VALUE'' WHERE LAB = ''OLDVALUE''';
    END LOOP;

    COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write pl/sql for this.

The first thing is, please don't use `SYSTEM.COL`. Instead use the data dictionary view `USER_TAB_COLS` or `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`. (or `ALL_TAB_COLS` if in other schema)

`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` would be what you want here.

```
BEGIN
   FOR i IN (SELECT table_name
               FROM user_tab_cols
              WHERE column_name = 'LAB')
   LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
         'UPDATE ' || i.table_name || ' set LAB = :value where LAB = :oldvalue'
         USING 'value', 'oldvalue';
   END LOOP;
END;
```

You can (and should) use a bind variable for value and oldvalue, just not for the table name.